# Problems with https on iPad from Air app

Tags: apache-flex, ipad, air, https

I have developed an in-house Air app for the iPad that tries to connect to a jetty web server via SSL (https) using HTTPService. Even the simplest GET returns error #2032 (runs OK with plain http).

I have checked the obvious things: URL is correct, certificate is correct and correctly installed, I am using the right port, which is open. As a matter of fact, the URL can be accessed from Safari on the iPad without problems. It also runs correctly on adl.

I am using an iPad 2 with iOS 5. The application was built with Air 4.6.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your server should host a crossdomain.xml file. Cfr. http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. The PC version of the application runs without problems. Using http on the iPad works too.

Comment: could you post a full stacktrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have posted in my Thread. 
I found a solution for this problem by myself. it works fine for me.

If you have a certificate which is signed by a third company it should work. if not, do the following steps:

First I have changed the contentType from the loader ( I use the HTTPService from Flex)  to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; but I think its only important in my case.

Second created a StageWebView, place it on stage and give it a viewport outside the screen. Than call the function loadURL from the StageWebView with your https url on startup of the application.

If the application runs on an ios device, a dialog apears that ask you if you want to allow a selfsigned certificate.  After you have accept the certificate the  next request will work.

There are two disadvantages:
• You have to accept the certificate on every new Startup of the app.
• You first call (over the stageWebView)  will not work. Because this calls the dialog and you cant dispatch the dialog input.  So you have to handle it by yourself that you make your HTTPS request after that dialog.

Comment: +1 and thanks. Unfortunately, my customer uses self-signed certificates. The idea of the StageWebView is quite creative. I would rather wait for Adobe to upgrade de socket components for mobile Air, though (or that Oracle decides to release JavaFX for iOS, and then make the switch).

Answer (score 0):

https is not yet supported in mobile Air applications

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what @Eduardo posted, HTTPS works just fine in AIR, as long as the certificate is valid.

Comment: My certificate is valid. Self-signed, but valid.

Comment: A self-signed certificate is not valid until you have manually trusted it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to upgrade your AIR version from 3.1 to latest one. Adobe AIR 3.2 also supports self signed certificate.