# Try to make Https Request on Adobe Air mobile apps with Actionscript Flex

Tags: security, mobile, air, https, adobe

I try to make an https request from a mobile iOs Device. This isnt working. In the flashbuilder simulator (on Mac) I have to accept the self-signed certificate but  its working fine. 
On the mobile device I've got the

> error 2032

I also have the same problem on an web mirgrated Version of the app. 
I have added on the server root  the crossdomain.xml:

```
site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"
allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"
```

In the project i use the  mx.rpc.http.HTTPService class. And i tried to change the destination type but with no effect:

```
useProxy = true;
destination = 'DefaultHTTPS';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem, and have asked the question before:

[Problems with https on iPad from Air app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249793/problems-with-https-on-ipad-from-air-app)

Unfortunately, it is not possible. The Air sockets implementation for mobile devices is lagging behind the one for desktop environments, and SSL is not supported. At this point, your best bet is to use an ANE.

Comment: i found a solution for this problem by myself. The it works fine. 

If you have a certificate which is signed by a third company it should work. 

first i have changed the contentType  to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; but i think its only important in my case.